# how to define a variable that all the classes can access in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Like: 
 - Class1, I have a variable called tempData.
 - In Class2, it can assign value to tempData. etc. `tempData = @"apple";`
 - In Class3, it can get the value of tempData. etc. `class3Data = tempData`. `//class3Data's value is "apple".`

What should I do?

Comment: sharedmanager may be is an option

Comment: Which way did you finally choose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either make a Sharedinstance of class1 by using this code

```
+ (Class1 *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static Class1 *shared;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^ { shared = [[Class1 alloc] init]; });
    return shared;
}
```

and access your variable as `[Class1 sharedInstance].tempData` wherever you want. But if you want to use simple a small data like a string or an integer. You should make a static variable outside the body of any class anywhere in your application. Only you need is to make that visible to the part where you want to use. Like in a file Class.h, declare this

```
static NSString *tempStr = @"test";

@interface Class
//code goes here of class
@end
```

and use this to any where. Just use `#import"class.h"` where you want to use this.

**NOTE: The better way to do the second approach is to make a constant file (Header file) and declare your global variable in that class**

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution (for constants) is to create a new Header file (.h) and to declare constants as follow :

```
#define API_ADDR @"http://anURL.com"
```

Everywhere you need it, just import `ExternalVariables.h` and :

```
NSLog(@"%@", API_ADDR);
```

Hope this helps.